# Simulating file transfer through Thread.sleep()

Tags: java, simulation, benchmarking, performance-testing, testbed

I need to simulate file transfer of particular size by Thread.sleep(). I have 4 files sizes-1KB, 10KB, 100KB and 1000KB.

What is the standard file transfer rate served by web servers which I can assign to these files?

I am simulating a web server behavior.For example, if a HTML file of 1kb is transferred in 1 millisecond then I will simulate it by Thread.sleep(1).

Any suggestions in this regard will be great.
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Just pick a time. Transfer speeds are limited by a billion different factors, there's no standard that will 100% emulate "xx milliseconds == yy kB"

Answer (score 0):

If you need to wait the amount of time of a file transfer you need to determine the system you are going to mock, and take in account of every possible problem you can have on that system ([latency for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_latency_and_throughput#Latency)).

If we are talking about an integration test you must absolutely do, this link could be useful:
http://techinternets.com/copy_calc?do